# How to pass a QTextEdit to signal/slot mechanism

Tags: qt

I have read some topics here about signals and slots and its parameters but found nothing about following problem:
I am working with Qt 5.7

I simply have 2 classes, inside 1st, I want to emit signal with string **message** and **location**(or specific object) where to display it.

**Now it is like this: I have 1st class where I emit signal :**

```
    emit signalWriteToTextEdit("hallo","textEdit_3");
```

What I want to do is somehow pass as the second argument an object like textEdit. No QString as its now.

**Inside 2nd class is the slot:**

```
void writeToTextEdit(QString info, QString where){   
    where.append(info); //I would like to do something like this
}
```

Just dont know how to consider that second parameter "where" as accessible object for example textEdit, so I could change its content.

I am thinking also if this is possible:

1. Is there some method for Ui object like finding elements by name?
2. Is it possible to go with foreach over all elements in ui and check their names...? I tried but dont know how to go through that.

If its not clear, I will explain more

Comment: You may use `QSignalMapper` http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalmapper.html

Comment: @DmitrySazonov thanks, I am going to read it

Comment: Btw, if you have a pointer to object as a "second argument", why you simply don't want to call a method? Why do you need signals there?

Comment: well, I dont have pointer to that object, sorry if I wrote it wrong, but I would like to somehow work with that string(second arg) as with textEdit in another class. 

Maybe something simplier than QSignalMapper would work. Just to cast that string(sec arg) to type like textEdit, i dont know...

Comment: @DmitrySazonov 
now it came on my mind... do you think its crazy to just go through textEdits in foreach cycle and compare the textEdit name with second argument and if it is equal, than write to that????

Comment: @DušanTichý Didn't you just say you don't have access to the textEdit?

Comment: @mascoj I have it in that 2nd gui class

Comment: @DušanTichý So class 1 doesn't know anything about the GUI elements? In that case you are pretty limited to having a mapping between a key and the element you want to write to. I would recommend establishing a static map at start time for quicker lookup rather than loop each time.

Comment: @mascoj good point, thanks iteration would be slower ha.

Comment: I have to agree with @DmitrySazonov above.  Your emitter has *almost* enough data to do what's required -- the name of the `QTextEdit` -- but no direct access to the `QTextEdit`.  That's a very odd way to partition functionality between sender and receiver.  How did the emitter get the `QTextEdit` name in the first place?  Could it not have been passed a pointer to the `QTextEdit` rather than simply its name?

Comment: @G.M. I use it for writing output to specified textEdit. I didnt want to write method for each textEdit like:
writeToTextEdit1
writeToTextEdit2
writeToTextEdit3
I want to do it by parameter, so its me who writes where its gonna go.
Why its odd?

Comment: But when I am thinking of it, it might be better to have specified functions to specified outputs ? Is it better to do it like this?

Comment: @G.M. He stated that the gui class is the receiver of the signal and the class sending the signal has no access to the gui element.

Comment: Nothing wrong with having separate methods for appending text to different `QTextEdit`s. Seems like the best solution with the info you've provided so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little digging, I came across the [QObject::findChild](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#findChild) function. This will allow a string lookup recursively through the UI, those I am unsure of performance.

Edit for more detail:

> Returns the child of this object that can be cast into type T and that is called name, or 0 if there is no such object. Omitting the name argument causes all object names to be matched. The search is performed recursively.
>
> If there is more than one child matching the search, the most direct
>   ancestor is returned. If there are several direct ancestors, it is
>   undefined which one will be returned. In that case, findChildren()
>   should be used.

Comment: yep, i found it, but this method doesnt have my ui object

Comment: @DušanTichý: you call it on the widget that you passed to your ui object's `setupUi()` method.

Comment: Dunno why, it gives me acces violation error, trying to do that on parent

Ap( QWidget *parent)
 : QWidget(parent)
{
 ui.setupUi(this); }

Answer (score 0):

Just use `QWidget*` or `QObject*` (if it is not always a widget) as the argument type

```
signals:
    void writeToTextEdit(const QString &what, QWidget *where)
```

or if it is always a `QTextEdit` even more specifically

```
signals:
    void writeToTextEdit(const QString &what, QTextEdit *where)
```

Though it is not clear why the code needs to emit a signal if it has access to the target object, it could simply call `setText` directly

Comment: well it doesnt, gui class is reciever, and the other class is not having access. 

ok, your solution is that but how will I emit that when I dont want to create new QTextEdit or QWidget. You know what i mean?

Comment: really depends on what you goal is. If you want to create a new object and have the receiver add it to its layout, then yes. But in this case you can just emit the new widget and have its content set before.

But from reading the comments on the question that seems not to be the case. If you only have different types of output, I would agree with G.M. and thuga that you should let the source just decide on the type and the target how it wants to handle them.
Either by different signals for the types or by having a type argument the receiver can switch on